# Gnome 3.20 graphical glitches when switching applications

Tags: gnome, gnome3, graphics, nautilus, intel-graphics

Today, I upgraded from Gnome 3.18 to 3.20 and started experiencing some strange graphical issues when changing focus from one application to another, either by alt-tab or clicking the new window with the mouse. So far, I have only seen this issue with gnome-apps (those that have the gnome-specific headerbar, such as Nautilus and gedit), and not with other apps (such as gnome-terminal and Firefox).

The specific graphical glitch varies a bit depending on which program is focused. I [uploaded a video](https://vid.me/cCES), documenting the behavior. It looks like the Nautilus and gEdit windows are trying to resize and switch to black, while the gnome tweak tool window actually resizes as it loses or gains focus. In contrast, the gnome calculator is not affected.

I had disabled all extensions and removed my `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, when recording the video. I am on Antergos (an Arch derivative), with kernel 4.5.0-1-ARCH. My machine is a ThinkPad Yoga 12 second edition laptop, with an Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) graphics card and the following graphic packages installed.

**xf86-video**

```
extra/xf86-video-fbdev 0.4.4-5 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]
extra/xf86-video-intel 1:2.99.917+560+gd167280-1 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]
extra/xf86-video-vesa 2.3.4-2 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]
```

**libva**

```
extra/libva 1.7.0-1 [installed]
extra/libva-intel-driver 1.7.0-1 [installed]
```

**Mesa**

```
extra/glu 9.0.0-4 [installed]
extra/libtxc_dxtn 1.0.1-6 [installed]
extra/mesa 11.2.0-1 [installed]
extra/mesa-libgl 11.2.0-1 [installed]
extra/mesa-vdpau 11.2.0-1 [installed]
multilib/lib32-glu 9.0.0-3 [installed]
multilib/lib32-libtxc_dxtn 1.0.1-5 [installed]
multilib/lib32-mesa 11.2.0-1 [installed]
multilib/lib32-mesa-libgl 11.2.0-1 [installed]
```

Any advice on what could be the cause of these glitches and how I can fix them?

---

### Update 2016-04-18

Apparently, in addition to disabling the usertheme addon, I needed to select Adwaita as the GTK+ theme in order to get the default gnome behavior. The issue goes away when doing this, so it seems to be a problem unique to the Numix Frost and Numix Frost Light themes, that Antergos use by default. So at least I can work around this by using another theme for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in the Numix themes and [it is being tracked here](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-gtk-theme/commit/3cc526c0d6b1a59049b3d91ba490fb66b5281f1c?diff=unified).